# Getting Memory Insufficient Error while saving template in Business Objects

Tags: business-objects

Getting Memory Insufficient Error while saving template in .xls format in Business Objects. How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the memory that's allocated in the CMC has been exceeded. You would need have admin rights to change the settings for the universe.

If you don't, the easier workaround is **limiting/filtering** your query so that the returned results/rows are relatively lesser. Then you can try to export your report again.